# Ensuring Library changes are committed before Project changes?

Tags: git, version-control, build, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a cross-platform Project that depends on a number of my own Libraries. The Project and each Library have their own respective repositories, that see regular changes.

The Libraries are abstract modules that are still evolving alongside the Project, but which aren't specific to that Project (although currently, said Project is driving most of those changes). The Project depends on these, so Library changes should always be committed before associated Project changes (i.e. changes which have been made because of changes to the Library interface).

**My problem is I often forget to commit the Libraries' changes first,** in SourceTree.

For now, I've created hard links to the Library files, in my Project folder. This way, because the OS handles the links, I don't need silly relative paths that exit the Project folder (e.g. `../../../my.h`), which may change when Project folder structure changes (as has just occurred). More to the point, this ensures that I will see changes to these files in SourceTree (in the Project), and commit them every time as part of the Project. Re the Library repos, well, I can commit the same changes as and when I finally notice in SourceTree that those repos have changesets (this being the task I usually forget to do first). Good enough... for now.

**Is there a better way to handle this simply?** I would prefer not to have Libraries  committed as part of the Project *also* - unnecessary duplication. I've also tried .gitignore on the hard links in the Project, so that I will never commit them as part of the Project repo, but then of course I am back to square one - because I only look at the Prject, I still forget to commit Library changes before Project changes... *which means any given build may be broken because associated Library changes are not present for that commit*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like git submodules are the way to go. Fortunately they are supported in SourceTree.